# Tagging array contents

Tags: php, arrays

I don't really know how to explain this but I will give an example.

I have an array (in PHP) which is

```
array(
    [0] => some string is here
    [1] => some more string here
    [2] => [TAG]
    [3] => something is here
    [4] => this string needs tag too
)
```

How can I convert this array to this:

```
array(
[0] => [ALL]
[1] => some string is here
[2] => [ALL]
[3] => some more string here
[4] => [TAG]
[5] => something is here
[6] => [ALL]
[7] => this string needs tag too 
)
```

If the pervious array key doesn't have a tag, just adds the [ALL] tag

This is what i've done so far

```
$a = "some string is here 
some more string here
[TAG]
something is here
this string needs tag too";

$cleanarray = explode("\n", $a);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($cleanarray); $x++) {
    $pervline = $x - 1;
    if ((substr($cleanarray[$pervline], 0,1) != '[') && (substr($cleanarray[$x], 0,1) != '[')) {
        $cleanarray[$x]="[ALL]\n".$cleanarray[$x];
    }
}
$cleanarray = explode("\n", implode("\n", $cleanarray));
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [ALL]
    [1] => some string is here 
    [2] => some more string here
    [3] => [TAG]
    [4] => something is here
    [5] => [ALL]
    [6] => this string needs tag too
)
```

Comment: You could write some code to do it. If you get stuck, ask again.

Comment: [TAG] and [ALL] are array?

Comment: @PragneshChauhan they are strings. I just added my codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'some string is here',
    'some more string here',
    '[TAG]',
    'something is here',
    'this string needs tag too'
);

print_r($array);

$tag = '[TAG]';
$size = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
    if ($array[$i - 1] !== $tag && $array[$i] !== $tag) {
        array_splice($array, $i, 0, array('[ALL]'));
        $i++;
        $size++;
    }

print_r($array);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/ba3e50ffbc28f9):

```
Array
(
    [0] => some string is here
    [1] => some more string here
    [2] => [TAG]
    [3] => something is here
    [4] => this string needs tag too
)
Array
(
    [0] => [ALL]
    [1] => some string is here
    [2] => [ALL]
    [3] => some more string here
    [4] => [TAG]
    [5] => something is here
    [6] => [ALL]
    [7] => this string needs tag too
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would achieve it through a combination of splicing and slicing.

Eg:

```
$half1 = array_slice($array, 0, 2); // first 2
$half2 = array_slice($array, 3, 2); // last 2
$half = array_splice($array, 2, 0); // [TAG]

$list = array();
foreach ($half1 as $h) {
    $list[] = '[ALL]';
    $list[] = $h;
}
$list[] = $half;
$list[] = $half2[0];
$list[] = '[ALL]';
$list[] = $half2[1];

print_r($list); // should return your array
```